# Problems with importing PyQt5 modules, the programs crashes: Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)

Tags: error-handling, pyqt5, python-import

Even if I create a file with this only line:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore
```

it crashes and gives me the error I reported in the title. This didn't happen before today, and I don't get why. I'm using PyCharm and I installed PyQt5 via its Settings-->Project: Project_Name-->Project interpreter

Can someone argue what's happening?

SOLVED: 
Just uninstalled and re-installed PyCharm

Comment: Many times the IDEs have problems in providing the error message, so I recommend you run it in the CMD, there you will find the complete error message, on the other hand it would be helpful to indicate which is your OS.

Comment: Hi @eyllanesc,
I'm working on Windows 10.
Do you mean Python CMD? If yes, there I can import only built-in libraries, no PyQt5 or anything. If you mean the command prompt of my pc, I really don't know how to run Python commands on it.
Sorry for my newbieness

Comment: I mean the CMD of your PC, run it with `/path/of/python.exe  /path/of/your/script.py`

Comment: Thank you very much for your promptness!